# Get class's property name at compile time without object instantiation

Tags: c#, properties, nameof

Is it possible to get the name of class's property (attention!) at compile time and without object instantiation?
With instantiation it can easely be done with nameof():

```
class DummyClass
{
    public int DummyProperty { get; set; }
}
void Meth()
{
    //With instantiation
    var dc = new DummyClass();
    var prname = nameof(dc.DummyProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `nameof(DummyClass.DummyProperty)`, if I understood you correctly.

There is a similar example for such a use case at [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof).

> Used to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of a variable, type, or **member**.

Comment: But it's not static?!

Comment: @Rekshino It's still possible

Comment: Indeed! Thanks!