# Why member access modifier does matter for nameof()?

Tags: c#, .net, nameof

I'm a little bit confused with `nameof()` operator. So for example I can't use class's private fields in `nameof()` in another class, but I can use `public` non `static` fields [using non static property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50391110/7713750), so I don't need instantiated object.

Is it consistently? Why member access modifier does matter for nameof()?

```
class A
{
    private int X;
    public int Y;
    public A()
    {
        var x = nameof(A.X);//OK
        var y = nameof(A.Y);//OK
    }
}
class B
{
    public B()
    {
        var x = nameof(A.X);//Compilation error
        var y = nameof(A.Y);//OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of access modifiers like `private` is to hide the implementation details. They are saying "Nope, you don't need to know this. This is implementation detail". That's why `nameof` is not allowed to access private properties. Whatever class you are in, that class should not know about the implementation details of some other class.

Static vs non-static is different. Its purpose is not to hide something that you don't need to know about. Its purpose is just to distinguish between members that belongs to instances of the class and members that belongs to the class itself. All you want here is just the name of that member, which requires no instances to be created, so why disallow you? Note that the member is accessible i.e. it's not something you shouldn't know about.

Comment: Yes, "the purpose" is the key word!

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I usually get around this but using a static helper class:

```
class A
{
    public static class Properties
    {
        public const string X = nameof(A.X);
    }

    private string X { get; }
}
```

Then using

`A.Properties.X`

It's a little bit more verbose, but still enables refactoring tools to work effectively.

Comment: I think exposing the name in order to invoke it by reflection is wrong. Suppose you don't need the private member anymore... how are you going to update your Properties? When the private string is an internal detail to your assembly you could make it an internal property and nameof just works.

Comment: @Wouter I agree, but sometimes an ORM or other framework assumes you have all public members. I certainly wouldn't do this for a published library.

Answer (score 1):

Field `X` in class `A` is private. door is locked, you cant access it no matter what you do.

This is not a `nameof` problem, its *Access Modifier* problem

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

> All types and type members have an accessibility level, which controls
>   whether they can be used from other code in your assembly or other
>   assemblies. You can use the following access modifiers to specify the
>   accessibility of a type or member when you declare it:

and

> - public The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.
> - private
>     **The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class or struct**.
> - protected The type or member can be accessed only by code in the same class, or in a class that is derived from that class. internal
>     The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly,
>     but not from another assembly.
> - protected internal The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, or from within a derived class
>     in another assembly.
> - private protected The type or member can be accessed only within its declaring assembly, by code in the same class or in a type that is
>     derived from that class.

Comment: But does `nameof(x)` _access_ member `x`? It certainly does not evaluate it. You should add a source for this detail, for completeness sake.